# Using history.state to save scrollTop?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

My over-engineered webapp:

- Uses `history.pushState` and `popState` events, to animate movement between URLs, without having to use a `#` in the URL.
- Uses an outer div to handle the scroll-bar, and the html and body have `overflow:hidden`. This is so when the user clicks back, it will not jump to the top before animating left.

Now my question is, if the user clicks the forward button again, how can I preserve where they were scrolled / scroll them back down to where they were.

- My first thought is to use the `history.state` object as a place to save the scrolled position, and then load it up when the user clicks forward. (I would have to `replaceState` on the first page which has no `history.state` object.) The problem with this idea is that once the user clicks back, I no longer have access to add the scrollTop to the current state.
- My next idea is to use a separate array, so I pull up the scroll location by index, but the problem with that is that if the user closes the tab and then re-opens it, or if they navigate to another site and come back to mine later, their forward-backward history is saved, but my separate array of `scrollTop`s would be lost.

What is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, one can use the state object of the history API to track the current state of the page (e.g. scroll positions or form field entries).

At some point, of course, one has to store the page state into the history state object. When the browser has fired a popstate event, however, it is already too late because the previous history state will already be replaced by the popped one.

So one has to store the page state before the popstate event. As there is no beforepopstate event, however, the only possible way to do this is to listen constantly to changes in the page state (e.g. to scroll or input events) and constantly update the current history state object with replaceState.

In Chromium-based browsers, however, every call to replaceState shows the loading indicator briefly to the user. If you don't want this, just call replaceState once after a popstate event. In this call, store a unique id in the history state object. Use this unique id as a key to store further state in the browser's session storage. (You would have to model a cache because entries might become state.)

Comment: There is no need to listen constantly to changes. In my SPA when user clicks a link or does something that updates the view I call pushState to store the new state in browser history and update URL in browser address bar. Now to make sure on returning to previous page via back button I end up on correct scroll position whenever user does any action that requires a change to state, I first invoke history.replaceState() to update the previous state in history and then update my view and call the history.pushState(). Now back/forward buttons work flawlessly in regards to scrollbar position.

Answer (score 1):

[Jörn Zaefferer](https://github.com/jzaefferer) has written an approach for exactly this problem: https://github.com/jzaefferer/pitfalls-examples/blob/master/app/gallery/gallery.js#L29-37

(If your native language is german, take a look at his talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGdbfKgPKI8)

Answer (score 0):

With pushState you can add data to your history states ,like this:

```
var stateObj = { scrollTop: "500px" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "page.html");
```

When the event of window.onpopstate is fired, it will return the stateObj (event.state), and there is your scrollTop position.

There is a nice plugin to control windows history:

jQuery Dynamic URL: https://github.com/promatik/jQuery-Dynamic-URL

Look at this example: http://promatik.no.sapo.pt/github/dynamic-url/

Comment: I realize that I could use `pushState` data, but I don't know what the scrollTop is at the point of `pushState`, because the user may scroll up or down before clicking back.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, probably the best way is to create your own system to manage that data and save those positions in cookies ...